# Loading and saving files in a text based game (java)

Tags: java

So, i'm trying to save my player data onto a txt file, then load the data from the text from when the game is opened again, but its not working, I get it to save while in the game, but when I close the game, and open it back up its no longer saved, and it has all the default data in the game, and in the file...

Here is the some of the code from the game (Sorry it's in pastebin, I thought i might be too long to just paste it into here.)

- [Game.java](http://pastebin.com/vsVmvzah)
- [Save.java](http://pastebin.com/XqAuz0fk)

I am in need of some assistance, trying to get it to load from the text document, and when the game opens, not resetting the text document into its default settings.

Comment: Hi Joe, could you please point it out in which exact method you try to load and save your game? This can enable us to understand your code and try to solve your problem more quickly. :)

Comment: If your code is too long to post, try taking a smaller sub-section of code. Generally, if your code is too long to fit, you haven't done enough on your own to narrow down where the problem is occurring. logging is generally useful in this regard.

Comment: Examples on how to read and write to / from text files are very well-described [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42).

Comment: Because you say the data in the file is default when you restart your game i guess you are overwriting the file before you load the data into the game. To load the data into your game you should try to put the loader as early as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in `Save.savePlayer()`

At the beginning you declare `saveInfo` to hold the values that the game holds at that point in time. When initially loading they will hold the default values.

```
int[] saveInfo = { Game.hp, Game.level, Game.mana, Game.expTotal,
                    Game.goldTotal, Game.arrow, Game.shuriken, Game.bomb,
                    Game.hpPotion, Game.mpPotion, Game.potion, Game.items };
```

The variables here:`Game.hp=100`,  `Save.saveInfo[0]=100`

Then you set all of the game variables to `saveInfo` at the beginning of `Save.savePlayer()`

```
                    Game.hp = saveInfo[0];
                    Game.level = saveInfo[1];
                    Game.mana = saveInfo[2];
                    Game.expTotal = saveInfo[3];
                    Game.goldTotal = saveInfo[4];
                    Game.arrow = saveInfo[5];
                    Game.shuriken = saveInfo[6];
                    Game.bomb = saveInfo[7];
                    Game.hpPotion = saveInfo[8];
                    Game.mpPotion = saveInfo[9];
                    Game.potion = saveInfo[10];
                    Game.items = saveInfo[11];
```

The variables here:`Game.hp=100`,  `Save.saveInfo[0]=100`
They don't change because you just set them back to their default values.

Then you load the saved state but you don't do anything with the data. You should be setting the variables after loading here so they're set to the new saveInfo values instead of the old.

```
for (int i = 0; i < saveInfo.length; i++) {
    saveInfo[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.readLine());
}
```

Comment: So, I'm not really understanding, how can I fix this, I've tried doing numerous things to fix this, but none seem to work, and sorry i'm new at coding...

Comment: In the method called `savePlayer` put all the lines that look like `Game.hp = saveInfo[0]` after the for loop

Comment: Yea, I did that, and still didn't work, same problem is happening, but I think that was part of the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this part is the problem...

```
private void readPlayer(String filePath) {
    File inputFile;
    BufferedReader inputReader;

    try {
        inputFile = new File(filePath);
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

        Game.hp = saveInfo[0];
        Game.level = saveInfo[1];
        Game.mana = saveInfo[2];
        Game.expTotal = saveInfo[3];
        Game.goldTotal = saveInfo[4];
        Game.arrow = saveInfo[5];
        Game.shuriken = saveInfo[6];
        Game.bomb = saveInfo[7];
        Game.hpPotion = saveInfo[8];
        Game.mpPotion = saveInfo[9];
        Game.potion = saveInfo[10];
        Game.items = saveInfo[11];

        for (int i = 0; i < saveInfo.length; i++) {
            saveInfo[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.readLine());
        }

        inputReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

put these lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < saveInfo.length; i++) {
    saveInfo[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.readLine());
}
```

before

```
Game.hp = saveInfo[0];
Game.level = saveInfo[1];
Game.mana = saveInfo[2];
Game.expTotal = saveInfo[3];
Game.goldTotal = saveInfo[4];
Game.arrow = saveInfo[5];
Game.shuriken = saveInfo[6];
Game.bomb = saveInfo[7];
Game.hpPotion = saveInfo[8];
Game.mpPotion = saveInfo[9];
Game.potion = saveInfo[10];
Game.items = saveInfo[11];
```

in order to read the file before setting the game values...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind it, then using xstream and apache fileutils is an excellent solution and less coding. I am just sharing my thoughts.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

//saving your data
XStream xstream=new XStream(new DOMDriver());
String xml = xstream.toXML(yourGambeObj);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("yourfilename", xml);

//reading your data
Game gameData=xstream.fromXML(new File("yourfilename"),Game.class);

//now you can use access your methods n attribute. no conversion as you did in serialization.
```

Please download and add these jars.[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) &
[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this works great, but I'm trying to learn to code without using extra jars at the moment, because I'm new at coding. But thank you for this advise. I have found the answer to my problem already too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was fiddling around with some things, and I did it! So, the problem was, that i would load it from the save data, then write over it, then load it again, for some reason, it would do the whole Save.java 2 times and just save over it, but I put them all as public static voids and instead of calling the whole Constructor, I call them by individual methods by where and what they need to do, which seem to work great! Thank you all for all your help, it helped a lot!